# Angular custom Filter pipe after KeyValue pipe

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to implement a custom filter after using Angular's inbuilt Key Value pipe

I have an array with values for example

```
object= [
  { key: "Added_By", value: "Yi" },
  { key: "Assigned_To", value: "-" },
  { key: "Bought_Date", value: 43810 },
  { key: "Brand", value: "Samsung PM863" },
  { key: "Capacity", value: 3.84 },
]
```

I want to filter based on multiple incoming values but incoming values vary for example

It Could be 1 key/Value

```
Filter= [{ key: "Added_By", value: "Yi" }]// Return Object
```

or multiple

```
Filter= [{ key: "Added_By", value: "Yi" }, { key: "Bought_Date", value: 43810 }] //both matches return object

Filter= [{ key: "Added_By", value: "ABC" }, { key: "Bought_Date", value: 43810 }] //1 match but 1 doesn't return false
```

I want to return object if all the conditions are met

For a single key/value I tried

```
  let Key= Filter[0].key
  let Value=Filter[0].value
  let KeyFilter = object.filter(x => x.key === Key)
  if (KeyFilter[0].value.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(Value.toLowerCase()) !== -1)
            return items
```

But this approach only works only when 1 object is present in filter array

Comment: The naming scheme `{ key: "Added_By", value: "Yi" }` is misleading. Please try to make the question more straight forward and clear. Easier way would be show us the objects, or arrays of objects, your pipe, the HTML and your expected output from the input object.

Comment: @MichaelD when KeyValue pipe is used it converts object like this, I know it might be confusing but that is how I'm receiving my object

Comment: That is understood, but at the moment people are left to much guess work because your original object and your pipe unclear. What would make the question much clear is showing your input, your pipe, your current output and your expected output. That would make it much easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a function that accepts an **array of objects**, and an **object with key: value pairs**.

*The keys of objects in the array must match with object keys to work.*

I always use it when I need to filter an array based on various conditions.

```js
export const filterArray = (filterData, toBeFiltered) => {
  return toBeFiltered.filter(item => {
    for (const key in filterData) {
      if (item[key] === null || item[key] === undefined) {
        return false;
      } else {
        if (typeof filterData[key] === 'string') {
          if (!(item[key]).toLowerCase().includes((filterData[key].trim()).toLowerCase())) {
            return false;
          }
        } else if (item[key] !== filterData[key]) {
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
    return true;
  });
};
```

Hope it helps.